# How can I mark which rows come from which table when I do a join?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am joining two tables together with similar data, but I want to be able to identify which rows are coming from which table. I figure I can make a new column where I put either 'Both' if it exists in both tables, 'Table 1' if it exists in the first table but not the second, and 'Table 2' if it exists in the the second table but not the first. I know I'll need to write some kind of conditional statement, but I have no idea what that would be.

Comment: You use outer join or union?

Comment: You can use `select column_name as myColumn` and output column will have name "myColumn"

Comment: if you use a JOIN, then each ROW comes from both tables...  if you use a UNION then they come from different tables - in that case use the column with a fixed value in each part of the union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details of your answer are going to depend a LOT on the specific database platform you're using. With that said, most database platforms support a CASE statement, which allows you to conditionally return values (including static strings) based on a variety of conditions.

More generally, however, you're going to be doing an outer join based on Table 1 fields matching Table 2 fields. Within your code, if the Table 1 fields being returned are null, that indicates the data came from Table 2, and vice versa. If neither are null, the data came from both.

You also have another option, to

```
      select from Table 1 
UNION select from Table 2
```

Then you can have a static field indicating which table each record is from, such as

```
      SELECT 'Table 1' table, field1, field2 FROM Table1 
UNION SELECT 'Table 2' table, field1, field2 FROM Table2
```

This option will probably create more work in your code, but may put less burden on the database server.

There are probably more options, but those are the ones that jumped out at me.